# what kind of smart bridge do I need for a smart home new construction?

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch, data-wiring

So, doing wiring for a small, new construction, upside-down house by the river. I wanted to go smart home with Alexa. I want to use Alexa exclusively if at all possible.
No appliances bought, or thermostat, and I have the smart outlets and switches.
What I need to know is what Smart Bridge to buy that will allow me to use the Alexa app. only!
or is this question N/A?

(smart lights, thermostat, Alexa, fans, sprinklers, cameras, shades, and doors [think star wars]).

Comment: If I was going for a smart home, I would make sure not to be tied into one company.  Too many stories of a company going under or changing their systems and people end up with pet rocks.  Exercise is good for your health.

Comment: And you also want to make sure you don't end up in a situation where you can't turn on/off your lights, etc. because the internet connection went down.

Comment: Or have root canal work done and it is pouring rain outside, so your voice does not match.

Comment: Or Alexa  just gets pissed at you.

Comment: You: "Alexa, turn on the kitchen light". Alexa: "I'm sorry, I can't do that Kevin, you know you shouldn't be eating a snack at 2am, it's not good for you."

Comment: Alexa won't work without internet - so if you loose internet you do loose any control.

Comment: I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that for you (from Space Odyssey, HAL)  There's no way I'd ever do a completely smart house:  Too many risks, too many points of failure, loss of power is a big one as well as loss of internet com.   For trivia junkies, HAL is one letter each off of IBM!!!

Comment: We can give opinions *today* about products that are going to work *today*.  But you know how it is, 5 years hence the company will be like "That thing is 3 generations old, we're gonna drop support".  This has happened over and over with smart home stuff.  You better put in conduit anywhere you might have to replace wiring later. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go control4.  You can get the alexa voice control that works with control 4.  If you loose internet you still have native control4 app or hard controls for backup.

I have control4, russ sound 4 zones, honeywell security (2 suites), lutron zigby lighting (all controllable via c4 iphone app).  I have hikvision 4 cameras (not integrated into c4).  I have rainbird for irrigation but also not integrated (haven't looked into it).  The lighting scenes are quite cool ( all-on, all-off, party, home, etc ).  You can do a all lights blink alarm mode if you want as well.  The scenes can be programmed by the installer.  At the entry I have a single gang switch box with 6 horizontal stacked keys which each do a scene.  I didn't go too crazy on the lights so I really just have the common areas and I kept the bedrooms/bathrooms dumb.

I haven't put in an alexa voice control for it but you can (probably in the future).  Star wars doors sound cool.  Sounds like budget isn't a problem so probably control4 is the premium option that is likely to integrate or have integration options available.

Be interested to see what you end up with.